# Qt: model/view - defining format of items holding date

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've a model which has items with `QDate` as `Qt::DisplayRole`/`Qt::EditRole`.
It works fine - view renders those items correctly and provides nice date editor. The only drawback is that I'd like to change date format being displayed.

Is there simpler way than preparing delegate with custom painting + `QItemEditorFactory` + `QItemEditorCreatorBase` etc?

It looks for me like the triumph of form over content.

Comment: Do you need an editor or you need just to display a text in a different format?

Comment: Can you give us a minimum code example to work with?

Comment: @SaZ: I need both: display text (date actualy) in specific format and then edit in specific format (yyyy-MM-dd is my target). As far as I can find in docs I need to prepare custom delegate and all this stuff for creating editor + editor itself (simply QDateEdit with format I mentioned).

Comment: You need just to implement custom delegate. It is not neseccary to override `QItemEditorFactory` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to display a date in specific cell you should subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and override it's `QString displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const;`

```
class DateItemDelegate :
    public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    DateItemDelegate (QObject* parent) :
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {};


    QString displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const
    {
        if (value.type() == QVariant::DateTime)
        {
            return value.toDateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate);
        }
    }
};
```

As for me you should use custom painting in case you want to display multiple data in one cell.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid :) as I'll also need to prepare custom editor which will be QDateEdit with specific format. But if there is no other way...

Comment: Other way to replace text (without editors) is to write your own `QIdentityProxyModel`. Imo, it is better to override `data` method in model, instead of delegates.

Comment: @SaZ if you mean override data so it return String instad DateTime then sorting will work incorrectly. Such item delegate dont affects sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all comments.

Summing up: there is no way to do it without custom delegate